# Different Route On Failed Different Authorization Policies asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using policy based authorization for my asp.net core application i have policies for minimum age requirement and valid subscription policies build with `IAuthorizationRequirement` interface and added like this

```
 options.AddPolicy(AccessConstant.GlobalAdmin,
                    policy => policy.AddRequirements(new GlobalAccessRequirement(AppConstants.Roles.Admin)));
```

my problem is once let say user failed on valid subscription requirement policy so i don't want user redirect to same access denied page instead of that i want redirect user to subscription renewal page same as i do minimal age requirement policy.

1. First, is there any build in way to implement these requirement on dotnet
   core or do we need to implement it.
2. how to handle that kind of scenario (any code sample really appreciate)

Regards

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth i came up with replacing view result on controller context. if you need i could give you code sample. may be not the best option ..

Comment: Nah it's ok, I'll keep digging.

Comment: @adam if you found good solution please share

Comment: I've put this down for the time being because we haven't fully defined the policies for our app, so there is no redirection necessary. My initial assumption, however, is that we need to use a custom pipeline handler to respond to a failed claims and understand why the failure occurred or with what resource, to drive redirecting.